# MPI_Bcast deadlock issue

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi, deadlock, broadcast

I wrote a program in which a process communicates an array of doubles using MPI_Bcast. It was working as expected for any number of processes on regular sized arrays, but when I tried broadcasting an array with more than 254 doubles a deadlock condition seems to occur. The receiving processes are held up in the receiving broadcast operation, and the sender performs the call and moves on. Are there any memory limits to MPI_Broadcast? What could be the pontential source of this problem?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: My guts tell me this is a bug in the code, but unless you show it here, that's all I can tell you.

Comment: Please provide MCVE.

Comment: Number one reason is that you are not calling the broadcast function in all ranks or that you are not following the same order while calling multiple collectives consecutively.